# Android: scrollbar track thinner than thumb in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

How can I set the scrollbar track thinner than the thumb in RecyclerView without using custom scrollView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_view_gradient"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@color/scroll_bar_track"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use a scrollbarTrackVertical drawable that is an image with a thin line in the centre and transparency on either side. So even though the "physical" track is larger, visually it seems smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Example of how it looks at the end]
I did this on my own, it looks 'nice' & it acts 'somewhat nice', but some things aren't tested enough, should be somewhat helpful at least. Can check it on [this link](https://coffeecode97.medium.com/recyclerview-custom-thumb-size-length-136f1836af9c) as well. Also, this first is just visually, if you want to customize the length of the thumb, then you need to create a custom view and manipulate the offset. Since it isn't a part of the question(and this answer), I didn't write it, it can be found in the link above if someone does need it.

bottom, left, right & top are insets, you can think of them as paddings, they don't affect the layout size, but you should keep the top & bottom insets on track and thumb on the same size(for vertical recyclerviews, horizontal ones should use left & right).
Also  manipulates the thickness of thumb and track, and stroke width places transparent pixels, so that track seems smaller than it actually is. Kudos to @Razvan S.
scrollbar_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/scroll_bar_color" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <size android:width="4dp"
                  android:height="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This doesn't need width & height properties, because recyclerview calculates the length automatically, and track width sets the thumb width.
thumb_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/scroll_bar_color" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="scrollbar_style">
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/thumb_shape</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_track</item>
</style>
```

recyclerview tag in your layout: ****style="@style/scrollbar_style"****

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/scrollbar_style" />
```

Now comes the 2nd part, if you want to manipulate the length of the thumb, you need to calculate the offset on your own. I did that by creating a **Custom RecyclerView** which implements **ScrollingView**, and calculated manually everything.

Hope this helped you, it did the job for me.

Also for those of you wondering, I used layer-list because it worked as I wanted it, if I switched to something else I didn't get the desired behavior. It's probably a bit flawed, and there might be a better solution somewhere out there, but I did this by trial&error until I produced something I could work with.